# sed -e 's/^[0-9]//' does not work for the first line

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

The following is the text I want to parse with sed (Mac OS X 10.11.1 bash)

```
1
00:25:43,959 --> 00:25:46,502
Here you are, sir.
Main level, please.
```

I can delete the first line with `sed -e 's/[0-9]//'`.

But with `sed -e 's/^[0-9]//'`, the first line, i.e. `1`  remains there.
Since `1` is at the beginning of the first line, shouldn't it be deleted?

head -n1 2001.srt | od -c

```
0000000  357 273 277   1  \n
0000005
```

Just created a new text file starting with "1".
head -n1 2002.srt | od -c

```
0000000    1  \n
0000002
```

sed -e 's/^[0-9]//' works for this newly created file.

Yes, there's something before "1".

Comment: It is probably not at the beginning. Most likely you have a non-printing character there. Please [edit] your question and post the output of `head -n1 file | od -c`.

Comment: In addition to @terdon, you can also say you have proven with `sed -e 's/^[0-9]//'` that `1` is not the first character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file starts with a UTF-8 [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). It is unicode symbol U+FEFF which is encoded as three bytes in UTF-8. Those three bytes show up as `357 273 277` when you print them in base 8.

To the `sed` command those bytes at the start of the line means that `1` is in fact not the first character on that line. Many other tools will treat it the same way.

You need to remove the BOM before doing other processing in order to get a useful result. For instance you could start your `sed` script with `s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//` to remove the BOM. Your full command would then become

```
sed -e 's/^\xef\xbb\xbf//;s/^[0-9]//'
```